# How to add a Person detail page on the community builder

Tags: apex, community, salesforcedx, administration

[image]How do we add a detail page for person Account object from the community builder, when I click on add page and select Salesforce object I don't see Person Account being listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Person Accounts are really a combined Account and Contact record, so to add a detail page to the Community you should look for Account instead. Person Accounts have their own record type to differentiate them from Business Accounts.

Comment: So I have a tab clicking on which it pulls up Account list view filtered on person account record type, but clicking on it opens up the person account page layout. Now I want to make some changes on this layout using the community builder but if I use Account detail it will use Account Page layout instead of Person Account. the community is displaying the person account page layout when I click on the personAccount list view filtered record but it doesnt offer a option to edit the page.